# CSS3 Navigation submenu is not inheriting its class

Tags: html, css, navbar, submenu

I have been playing with CSS3 trying to really understand it and I have not been able to get the behavior of the sub-menu navigation to be correct.  Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jllcpp04/9Jpd6/7/ for a working example.  The sub-menu still has the bullet points on it and it is not popping up to the right. This is part of a dynamic menu whose width will change depending upon what offices will appear (based on user profile).  I would prefer not to set top/right/left/bottom for div location.  I also cannot figure out why derivnav is not overriding the nested submenu.

My HTML Code:

```
 <div class="main_nav">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="submenu"><a href="#" class="drop">Office</a>

                    <div class="subnav">
                         <h3>Near You</h3>

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="deriv"><a href="#" class="dropr">New York</a>

                                    <div class="derivnav">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Upper West Side</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Upper East Side</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lower West Side</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Wallstreet</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                         <h3>Not Near You</h3>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">chicago</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">philadelphia</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">san francisco</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Component CSS:

```
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
 .main_nav {
    width:56%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.nav {
    list-style:none;
    height:43px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
    min-width:775px;
    text-align:left;
}
.nav h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:7px 0 14px 4px;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #888888;
}
.nav h4 {
    font-size:12px;
    margin:7px 0 14px 4px;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #888888;
}
.nav > li {
    border:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:5px 3px 5px 2px;
    padding:auto;
}
.nav li {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #333333;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.nav li:hover > a, .nav li:hover > p {
    color:#cccc66;
}
.nav li .drop {
    padding-right:15px;
    background:url("drop-nonsel.png") no-repeat right 4px;
}
.nav li:hover .drop, .nav li .drop:hover {
    background:url("drop-sel.png") no-repeat right 4px;
}
.nav .subnav {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-top:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    /* Gradient background */
    background:#FFFFFF;
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.2s, opacity 0.2s linear;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.nav .submenu:hover .subnav, .nav li .subnav:hover {
    top:auto;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}
.nav .subnav > ul {
    padding:2px;
    margin:0 0 12px 0;
}
.nav .subnav > li {
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:thin;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
}
.nav .subnav > li:last-chid {
    border-bottom:none;
}
.deriv li .dropr {
    padding-right:10px;
    background:url("drop-right-nonsel.png") no-repeat right 6px;
}
.deriv li:hover .dropr, .deriv li .dropr:hover {
    background:url("drop-right-sel.png") no-repeat right 6px;
}
.subnav .derivnav {
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    right:-150px;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-left:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    /* Gradient background */
    background:#FFFFFF;
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.subnav .derivnav > li {
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:thin;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
}
.subnav li .deriv:hover .derivnav, .subnav li .derivnav:hover {
    top:auto;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}
.derivnav ul {
    padding:2px;
    margin:0 0 12px 0;
}
.derivnav li {
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:thin;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
}
```

I have been playing with it for a few days and can't seem to figure it out.  my CSS3 validates and my html code does as well.  Any ideas?

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: Minor detail first, the bullet points would go away if you add `li{ list-style-type: none; }` to the CSS like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xs6X/).

Comment: I tried that and it worked, but when I look at the class inheritance - the submenu derivnav is not being inherited which is where the problem is!  Thanks though for the first step!

Comment: Can you make a small image of the result you are trying to accomplish>

Comment: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css3-dropdown-menu/css-gradient-dropdown.html  where the third submenu displays to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me when I removed the `>` marks from these two lines:

#### Old version

```
.nav .subnav > li {

.nav .subnav > li:last-chid {
```

#### New version

```
.nav .subnav li {

.nav .subnav li:last-child {
```

The `>` in a CSS selector means that the selected element must be a direct child of the previous element, not just the nearest descendant. In your markup, `.subnav` is a `div`, not a `ul`. The `li` element simply wasn't selected before, so you're styles were never applied.

If you need the `.subnav` list styles to be completely separate from the `.deriv` styles, you could use the `>` operator like this:

#### Alternate

```
.nav .subnav > ul > li {
```

[My fork of the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/MJpG5/)

Comment: So using that demo - the submenu (3rd level) doesn't appear right along side the div.  http://jsfiddle.net/jllcpp04/MJpG5/8/ is an example of what happens when I remove the right position qualifier.  Is there a way to have it appear to the right?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/MJpG5/10/, I removed `float:right` and tweaked the `right` property to slide it back. I don't know if that's the correct solution for adding multiple menu items. I also removed the top right corner rounding on `.subnav` and the bottom left rounding on `.deriv`.

Comment: Thank you! This was tremendously helpful!

Answer (score 1):

i add    [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Jpd6/11/)

```
.nav li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #333333;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```